# Multiple instances of a library on Linux with separate data segments

Tags: c, linux, linker

I have some C code riddled with globals that I need to link together with my project. This external project is a live project being frequently updated, so rewriting the code to be more multiple-instance friendly is not a simple option. To give a concrete example, imagine we have the library code (ignore the unsafeness!):

```
// foo.c
static char s_memory[256];
static int s_length;

void foo_init(char **mem)
{
    *mem = s_memory;
}

void foo_calc(char *mem)
{
    s_length = strlen(mem);
}

int foo_result()
{
    return s_length;
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
// test_foo.c
char *data;
foo_init(&data);
strcpy(data, "Hello, world!");
foo_calc(data);
printf("%s is %d characters long!\n", data, foo_result());
```

This works fine for the single-threaded instance, but our team wants to run this in a multi-threaded environment, where obviously this is horribly wrong:

```
char *data1;
char *data2;
foo_init(&data1);
foo_init(&data2);
strcpy(data1, "Hello, world!");
strcpy(data2, "Goodbye cruel world!");
foo_calc(data1);
foo_calc(data2);
printf("%s and %s are %d and %d characters long!\n",
       data1, data2, foo_result(), foo_result());
```

What I hope we could do would be like:

```
char *data1;
char *data2;
FOO_HANDLE inst1 = new_instance("foo.so");
FOO_HANDLE inst2 = new_instance("foo.so");
inst1.foo_init(&data1);
inst2.foo_init(&data2);
strcpy(data1, "Hello, world!");
strcpy(data2, "Goodbye cruel world!");
inst1.foo_calc(data1);
inst2.foo_calc(data2);
printf("%s and %s are %d and %d characters long!\n",
       data1, data2, inst1.foo_result(), inst2.foo_result());
```

How can something like this be achieved?

Comment: Rewrite the code to do the job properly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did try that, but there's five or six levels of globals, a mix of module statics, globals pointing to other files, and malloced memory, and a long chain of pointer copying, working out lifetimes is a pain, and of course another team is updating the code, so merging their changes becomes a PITA. Ideally the other team should refactor their stuff, of course, but...

Comment: Software can be remarkably rigid at times.  However, I don't think there's a sane way to achieve what you're trying to achieve. If the code you show is representative of the code you want, thread-local storage isn't going to help.  You'll have to write code that uses the `new_instance` to allocate a structure (the argument is irrelevant) — probably a pointer, so you'd write `inst1->foo_init(&data1)` etc.  At some point, you'd have to release the data associated with the handle, to avoid memory leaks.  It's a slippery road.  Anything using the old interface can't be used multithreaded sensibly.

Comment: What @JonathanLeffler says, ideally by getting the 'other team' to rewrite their stuff, and test and debug it, to make it useable.  I can't see how you could make forward progress with this if someone else is continually making changes, adding more globals/statics, that actively defeat what you need to do:(  Is your CV up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest simple solution is to put `_Thread_local` (or `__thread`) on each global and access each instance from its own thread.

Another hack that would possibly work is to make a new copy of the .so file each time you want a new instance, and `dlopen`. Alternatively you could write your own ELF loader that allows multiple instances of the same library (not as hard as it sounds).

All these are bad hacks though and you **really** should just fix the code to remove all globals.

Comment: I don't think the TLS would work as the calling environment does not guarantee that either each `foo` client gets its own thread or that each call to a `foo` client is on the same thread.

Comment: @KenY-N: Indeed, that's a problem. You can possibly fix it by wrapping all the public interfaces to take a context argument, where the context is just the thread to run the function in and a command+mutex+condvar structure to communicate with the thread through, but that's getting to the point of being really heavy as a workaround for the bad API.